# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error in BlogEngine.NET

Tags: c#, .net, iis, blogengine.net, hosted

I'm trying to install [BlogEngine.NET](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/) in my Hosted Plan at arvixe.com

I get this error when I try to navigate to the Blog :

> The configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

```
53:     </system.serviceModel>
54:     <system.web.extensions>
55:         <scripting>
```

And here is my [web.config](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/cb68c2a2edcc#BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/Web.Config) file.

There is some articles on internet about get this fixed but the problem is :

1- I'm using the blog in a Hosted plan

2- I don't have access to the IIS configuration with Arvixe.

Do you think I can fixe this just by changing the web.config file ?

Comment: Is your hosting configured to run under .NET 4 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell your host to change the framework version your ***AppPool*** is tied to. Its probably tied to 2.0 which doesn't recognize system.web.extensions. It needs to be changed to 4.0

More info [here](http://blog.benday.com/archive/2010/05/19/23278.aspx) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1547286.aspx/2/10)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try: 
If the OS is 64bit, try to recompile your application in Any to have it run as a 64bit application. Or change the Application Pool to enable 32bit applications.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:
If the OS is 64bit, try to recompile your application in Any to have it run as a 64bit application. Or change the Application Pool to enable 32bit applications.

If that doesn't help, perhaps the web.config section is locked down, and you will then have to ask your hosting company to allow the section.